# Alternate mike / speakers

Tags: audio, configuration

I'd like to switch off/on alternatively the microphone and the speakers with a simple click to avoid looping the voice in the speakers in a conversation.
Is there such a possibility in a easy way ?

I thought maybe about a script, but in this case what are the bash commands to switch off/on the microphone and the speakers and how to test witch are on ?

Ubuntu 18.04 with Alsa.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command-line tool `amixer` which should allow you to perform the necessary tasks.

First, run

```
amixer controls
```

to get a list of control options. You will likely get output like

```
numid=XX,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'

...

numid=YY,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
```

You can get the status of the control option with

```
$ amixer cget name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=XX,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=off
```

To set, use

```
$ amixer cset name='Master Playback Switch' 'on'      
numid=XX,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
  ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
  : values=on
```

So, to switch to "speak" mode, you could use

```
amixer cset name='Master Playback Switch' 'off'; amixer cset name='Capture Switch' 'on'
```

and to switch to "listen" mode:

```
amixer cset name='Capture Switch' 'off'; amixer cset name='Master Playback Switch' 'on'
```

Comment: Thank you. amixer cset name='Capture Switch' 'on' and 'off' works fine, but amixer cset name='Master Playback Switch' 'off' or 'on' works rondomely mostly not.
How to have a switch button ?

Comment: Hm. Do you have other control options labelled "Playback Switch"? Maybe you can try those ...

Comment: I have a 'Speaker Playback Switch' that works only for off but not for on and then 'Master Playback Switch' works for on but not for off. Actually I'd like to use HDMI output but there is no switch for HDMI only numid=19,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'